# Simple web script

Tags: python, sockets, web, server

Basically I want to send information, say a string, to my website and then I want my website to write this information to a text file.

I'm using Python to send the info, and I've read about sending information via a socket, but how do I get my website to listen for this data? And what IP address do I send this data to if I want my website to receive it once this server is running?

Just ask me if something wasn't clear, I'm not even quite sure what I'm looking for hence why I can't just google it.

Comment: Can you just write the string straight from Python to the text file?  Why do you want to send it to a website in between?

Comment: So that if I run the script on one machine the information is accessible from any machine. Also, just to get a basic understanding of how to do such a thing.

Comment: You seem a bit confused about the concept of a "website" vs a "server". You host a website on a server. Specifically you use some kind of backend technology (eg some webserver such as apache/nginx with html/some cgi script/php) which runs on your server. This typically responds to HTTP requests on port 80. You could do what Meng suggests. You could also write your own "webserver", running a python program on the server which acts as a TCP server and listens to a particular port of your choosing. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html. There is no "website" involved here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentions "my website", which means you have control of the server, right?
So instead of playing the socket directly, I suggest that you build a API on your website.

The "API" may be just a page processing GET method. So you can send the message by request a special URL and the server will know what to do.

For example, if you have a special write_file.php on the server, and the client can request this: http://my.website.com/write_file.php?message=hello&user=my&password=pwd to write file. And as you see, you can even do authentication in this way. (Although still not very safe, but this is the idea)

Comment: I do indeed have control of the server, but I didn't know this was the way to go about communicating information to it. I'll look into it, thanks.

Comment: I was able to figure out how to do what I wanted via POST requests after a bit of research, so thanks for steering me in the right direction.